# changing the attribute value in non preserved key table(view) without knowing the base tables

Tags: sql

actually I am looking for the modification of value in password attribute of dba_users.
But whenever I am trying to update the value of password attribute then it gives an error
"cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table".

Is there any way to change the value of password attribute of dba_users view.
and what is the base tables of the this view.

Here is the code

```
update dba_users set password='01DA2594F386175C' where username='HR';
```

Here I am doing this on Oracle 10g

Comment: You should generally mention the system you are working with, so that it's possible for other to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Views cannot be updated in cases where there is no way for SQL to determine what to update. This isn't a SQL issue, this is a consequence of the logic of what a view is.

For instance, what if the username and password are not a 1-to-1 relationship? You could have multiple userIDs with the same username, but different passwords and the server has no way of knowing what to do.

Comment: In this case username is distinct and I have problem with the modification of the attribute value. If you have any idea about the base tables of dba_users view then please tell me. Thanks for your response.

Comment: There is no way to find out unless we know what system you are using, or some other data, per my comment to your question.

Comment: @R.K.Rahu - Also, regarding previous questions you have asked, it's considered polite to click the check-mark next to the answer that answered your question, as well as upvoting answers that have been useful to you.